# Simulating simultaneously pressing multiple keys in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like <kbd>AppsKey</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to simulate <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>LAlt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, and I thought the following script would do it, but it doesn't:

```
AppsKey & Delete::  
SendInput {LAlt down}{LCtrl down}{Delete}{LAlt up}{LCtrl up} 
MsgBox "You pressed AppsKey & Delete"
return
```

Any thoughts why?

**Note 1:**: The `MsgBox` command above works though and I get a window.

**Note 2:**: I tested this on Windows 7 64bit and Windows XP 32bit with no success.

Comment: Try removing the spaces between adjacent braces.  Also, can you verify that the script is actually executed when you hit AppsKey + Delete?  (Put a messagebox in there to check)

Comment: Thanks @Breakthrough, I just updated the post. The MsgBox statement works, but AutoHotkey doesn't seem to send `LCtrl`+`LAlt`+`Del`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the SendInput and Send help document, in some part says the following:

> the operating system does not allow simulation of the CTRL-ALT-DELETE combination, doing something like Send ^!{Delete} will have no effect

I think you need to find an alternative way to block the system, maybe using some Win API function call.

Link of the fr doc: http://autohotkey.free.fr/docs/commands/Send.htm

Link of the us doc: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: Thanks @voodoomsr, do you know by any chance what `^!`means in  `Send ^!{Delete}`?

Comment: Yes, !=Alt and ^=Ctrl